# Flutter Large Image : pixelated rendering problem

Tags: flutter, image, camera

In my flutter app,

I use camera package to take picture,
and preview image taken on result screen right after.

But in this result screen, Image was too pixelated.

| CameraPreview | By Image.file( ) |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before taking] | [image: On preview] |

```dart
// camera screen
XFile? picture = await controller.takePicture();
final image = (await imglib.decodeImageFile(picture.path))!;

// some cropping to rect. This is not a problem. When I uploaded the cropped image, Image was fine.
final cropped = image.resizeImageToRect(size: 720); // returns imglib.Image of size 720x720
File croppedFile = File(picture.path);
await croppedFile.writeAsBytes(imglib.encodeJpg(cropped, quality: 100));

Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/camera/result', {imagePath: croppedFile.path});
```

```dart
// result screen : build()
final file = File(args.imagePath);

// My phone is iPhone14 Pro, so this will render in area 393x393.
return AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1,
  child: Image.file(file),
);
```

Is there any workarounds?

I tried scale, width, cachedWidth, and filterQuality params on `Image.file()`. Nothing works.

Expects: like CameraPreview, rendering clean and sharp image.